# Обработка сложного запроса SQL в C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Как обработать сложный запрос в reader-ре C#?

Как реализовать вроде такого:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        offerModel.Add(new OfferModel
        {
            ID = (int)reader["ID"],
            NAME = (string)reader["NAME"],
            POS = (string)reader["POS"]
        });
    }
    reader.Close();
```

Запрос:

```
select @p1:=PARENT_ID,NAME,POS from personal where NAME = "Галлямов Артем Рифович" and TYPE = "EMP" and STATUS = "AVAILABLE"; 
select @p2:=PARENT_ID,NAME,POS from personal where ID = @p1  and TYPE = "DEP" and STATUS = "AVAILABLE"; 
select ID,@p3:=NAME,POS from personal where ID = @p2 and TYPE = "DEP" and STATUS = "AVAILABLE";
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш сложный запрос можно объединить в один, либо написать процедуру которая возвращает несколько `DataSets`
Переход на следующий `DataSet` происходит `Reader.NextResult()` далее как обычно, работаем с `DataSet`.